# Disable menus of browser using javascript without opening new popup

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Actually I want to protect my source code of my website  from everybody.
so I want to disable all sources of finding the code like: Ctrl+U, Ctrl+Shift+I,F12 and menu of browser.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to hide your source code. You could install a script to prevent right-clicking or encrypt your code with JavaScript, but that won't stop anyone that knows anything about web development from finding it.

Answer (score 0):

This will never work, and your effort is better spent elsewhere.

At the very least, a user can use a web proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to easily retrieve the source code.